# Efficiently calculate mean in a large C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, caching

I have a data set of 65K samples in 7 blocks: `float arr[7][65536]` I need to calculate the mean for each corresponding 7 numbers so the result will be an array of size 65536:

```
float result[0] = arr[0][0] + arr[1][0] + arr[2][0] + ... / 7
float result[1] = arr[0][1] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][1] + ... / 7
```

The problem is that accessing the memory not sequentially will create many cache misses, Is there a better way in terms of memory to approach this problem?
Reshaping the array in advance suffers from the same memory inefficiency.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the actual code that creates this 2-dimensional array.   We don't know if you dynamically created this array in a naive fashion that has the array elements strewn all over the heap, whether it is a "true" 2D array where data is in contiguous memory, etc.

Comment: Maybe, first `for (size_t j = 0; j < 65536; ++j) result[j] = array[0][j];`, then `for (size_t i = 1; i < 7; ++i) for (size_t j = 0; j < 65536; ++j) result[j] += array[i][j];`; and then `for (size_t j = 0; j < 65536; ++j) result[j] /= 7;`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - it's a true 2D array, continuous in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution is to walk through the contiguous dimension. However, if `sizeof(arr[0][0])` is quite big, this may not be optimal as `result` will not fit in the L1 cache. The optimal solution is probably to use blocking to solve this issue.

Here is a C++ example code to do that:

```
// Blocked reduction using blocks of size 1024
// This loop iterate over the blocks
for(size_t j=0 ; j<65536 ; j+=1024)
{
    for(size_t k=j ; k<j+1024 ; ++k)
        result[k] = arr[0][k];

    // Summation of the current block
    for(size_t i=1 ; i<7 ; ++i)
        for(size_t k=j ; k<j+1024 ; ++k)
            result[k] += arr[i][k];

    for(size_t k=j ; k<j+1024 ; ++k)
        result[k] /= 7;
}
```

Note that the type of `result` must be large enough to hold values 7 times smaller/bigger than the one of `arr[0][0]`. This loop should be vectorized by your compiler and should produce fewer cache misses, resulting in much faster code.

PS: if the loop is not vectorized, you can help your compiler by adding the OpenMP directive `#pragma omp simd` just before the inner `k`-based loops (and ensure OpenMP is enabled).

Comment: This is ~1.1 times faster than my naive solution when using `int` in `clang` according to [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/z-oXYUTI8Y4MHB8-Xc9qy5epXHU). With `gcc` your version is [~1.2 times faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/sgDzmNQKjOKvKe14ygtZ6chYghc)

Answer (score 2):

With hope that keeping the inner loop around the inner array will make good use of the cacheline (and therefore be faster than making the inner loop around the outer array) you could try this:

```
for(const auto& inner_arr : arr) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < std::size(inner_arr); ++i) {
        result[i] += inner_arr[i];
    }
}
for(auto& v : result) v /= std::size(arr); // div down to mean value
```

But you'll have to measure if it's actually faster / more efficient than what you have now.

A different apporach could be using the execution policies added in C++17. I've added a *counting iterator* for that to work. If you have `boost` you can use their *counting iterator* instead.

```
struct counting_iterator {
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = size_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using referece = value_type&;
    using difference_type = std::intmax_t;

    counting_iterator& operator++() { ++value; return *this; }
    counting_iterator operator++(int) { auto copy=*this; ++value; return copy; }
    bool operator==(const counting_iterator& rhs) const { return value == rhs.value; }
    bool operator!=(const counting_iterator& rhs) const { return value != rhs.value; }

    value_type operator*() const { return value; }

    size_t value;
}

// ...

std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, counting_iterator{0}, counting_iterator{65536},
    [&arr, &result](size_t i) {
        for(size_t o = 0; o < 7; ++o)
            result[i] += arr[o][i];
        result[i] /= 7;
    });
```

When using gcc and `int` as data type, this is ~1.4 times faster than my simple solution above according to [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/xj2ddpMjSJMKxwW807NRU38NCeU) and [~2.1 times faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/uNUXhSGGLVdAJYV7FFdRsrYoA3M) with clang. This may vary a lot depending on how many hardware threads you have available.